# How to Automatically Update TabPane Tabs in JavaFX After File Writing Has Occurred?

Tags: javafx

I am writing a program to store information about clients for a business.

I've created the button function member to add new client and it works fine.

However, I incorporate a TabPane into the top of my main JavaFX BorderPane and I am having issues automatically updating the tabs after that file is written and to do that it displays the newly added client to the tab list.

If I close the program and reopen it shows all information but I want to to update the tabs right after the submit button is clicked.

I have attempted use the TabPane in the app extends Application class, but then I can't access that from my Menu class. The overriding start method at subclassing the Application class is quite a headache with JavaFX.

Then, I attempted to  move the TabPane to its own class file and I realize that I have no idea how to force the tabs to update from the main App extends Application class...

How can I fix it?

Here is my main App class:

```
public class App extends Application {
//User screen size
private Rectangle2D screenSize = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();

//Main window and sub windows
private BorderPane mainWindow = new BorderPane();
private GridPane buttonTabPane = new GridPane();
private Menus menu = new Menus();

//Button bar
private ButtonBar buttonBar = new ButtonBar();
private Button newClient = new Button("New Client");
private Button editClient = new Button("Edit Client");
private Button findClient = new Button("Find Client");

//Client tabs
private Tabs clientTabs = new Tabs();
private TabPane clientTabPane = clientTabs.getTabPane();

//Padding
private Insets pad = new Insets(10);

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Cybernetic Tax Automation");

    //Button bar
    buttonBar.getButtons().addAll(newClient,editClient,findClient);
    buttonBar.setPadding(pad);

    //Button actions
    newClient.setOnAction(e -> {
        mainWindow.setCenter(menu.newClient());
    });

    //Combo pane for button bar and tabs
    buttonTabPane.setConstraints(buttonBar,0,0);
    buttonTabPane.setConstraints(clientTabs.getTabPane(),0,1);
    buttonTabPane.getChildren().addAll(buttonBar,clientTabs.getTabPane());

    //Find currently selected client tab
    clientTabs.getTabPane().getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(e -> {
        System.out.println(clientTabs.getTabPane().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText());
    });

    //Main window
    mainWindow.setTop(buttonTabPane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow,screenSize.getMaxX(),screenSize.getMaxY());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

}

Here is my Menu class that points to new client button window:

```
public class Menus {
//Menus
private GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

//System specific home
private String home = System.getProperty("user.home");

//File paths
private String clientsFilePath = "/Desktop/Clients.txt";

//Files
private Files fileIO = new Files();
private File clientsFile = new File(home + clientsFilePath);

//Padding and gaps
private Insets pad = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
private int gap = 10;

public GridPane newClient() {
    gridPane.setPadding(pad);
    gridPane.setHgap(gap);
    gridPane.setVgap(gap);

    Label firstName = new Label("First Name:");
    TextField firstNameField = new TextField();
    gridPane.setConstraints(firstName,0,0);
    gridPane.setConstraints(firstNameField,1,0);

    Label middleName = new Label("Middle Name:");
    TextField middleNameField = new TextField();
    gridPane.setConstraints(middleName,0,1);
    gridPane.setConstraints(middleNameField,1,1);

    Label lastName = new Label("Last Name:");
    TextField lastNameField = new TextField();
    gridPane.setConstraints(lastName,0,2);
    gridPane.setConstraints(lastNameField,1,2);

    Button submit = new Button("Submit");
    gridPane.setConstraints(submit,1,3);
    submit.setOnAction(e -> {
        String fullName = "";

        for(Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
            if(node instanceof TextField) {
                String firstLetter = ((TextField)node).getText().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
                String upperName = firstLetter + ((TextField)node).getText().substring(1);
                fullName += upperName + " ";
            }
        }

        fullName += "\n";

        fileIO.writeFile(clientsFile,fullName);
        firstNameField.clear();
        middleNameField.clear();
        lastNameField.clear();
    });

    gridPane.getChildren().addAll(
            firstName,
            firstNameField,
            middleName,
            middleNameField,
            lastName,
            lastNameField,
            submit
    );

    return gridPane;
}
```

}

Here is my recently created Tabs class:

```
public class Tabs {
//System specific home
private String home = System.getProperty("user.home");

//File paths
private String clientsFilePath = "/Desktop/Clients.txt";

//Files
private File clientsFile = new File(home + clientsFilePath);

//Objects
private TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
private Files fileIO = new Files();

public Tabs() {
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);
    tabPane.setTabMinWidth(120);

    updateTabs();
}

public TabPane getTabPane() {
    return tabPane;
}

public void updateTabs() {
    ArrayList<String> clientList = fileIO.readFile(clientsFile);
    tabPane.getTabs().removeAll();

    for(int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
        Tab client = new Tab(clientList.get(i));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(client);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Lot's of code, so I didn't read much of it. What it sounds like you need to do is after you write to the file, go ahead and create a new `Tab` using the same info you used to write to the file.

Comment: I think something like `public void addTab(String client)
{
 Tab client = new Tab(client);
 tabPane.getTabs().add(client);
}` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there can be other efficent ways to fix this, below is the one I can quickly think for now.

You can pass the Tabs instance to the newClient() method and request to update the tabs when the file writing is done.

So something like...

In your start() method:

```
newClient.setOnAction(e -> {
   mainWindow.setCenter(menu.newClient(clientTabs));
});
```

And in newClient method:

```
// PASS THE Tabs INSTANCE TO THIS METHOD    
public GridPane newClient(Tabs clientTabs) {
        gridPane.setPadding(pad);
        ...
        ...
        submit.setOnAction(e -> {
            String fullName = "";

            for(Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
                if(node instanceof TextField) {
                    String firstLetter = ((TextField)node).getText().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
                    String upperName = firstLetter + ((TextField)node).getText().substring(1);
                    fullName += upperName + " ";
                }
            }

            fullName += "\n";

            fileIO.writeFile(clientsFile,fullName);
            firstNameField.clear();
            middleNameField.clear();
            lastNameField.clear();
            // CALL THE UPDATE TABS WHEN THE FILE WRITING IS DONE
            clientTabs.updateTabs();
        });
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This worked well and automatically updated the tabs, however it created many duplicates of the previous tabs as well for some reason. I have my Tabs.updateTabs() method to clear all child tabs before it loops around and recreates all of them, so why would it create so many duplicates?

Comment: Can you provide the content in Clients.txt

Comment: Yes, so it would look something like this:

Michael David Rothenberger /
Ronald Sal Goldberg /
Sally Rose Johanssen

Essentially, the file contains one line strings of first, middle, and last names, even though I can't format it that way in this comment. After I clicked the save button, it didn't cause all the duplication in the file, just for the tabs themselves. It seems that the clients file remained completely in tact.